# Issue in Spotify search

Tags: ios, objective-c, spotify

```
NSString *strUrlSearch=@"http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=kaizers+orchestra";
    [[SPSession sharedSession] searchForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrlSearch] callback:^(SPSearch *search) {
        NSLog(@"search value %@",search);
        if (search != nil) {
            [SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:search timeout:kSPAsyncLoadingDefaultTimeout then:^(NSArray *loadedItems, NSArray *notLoadedItems) {
                NSLog(@"values %@",search);
                NSLog(@"values %@",search.tracks);
                NSLog(@"values %@",search.albums);

            }];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"search is nil ");
        }

    }];
```

My output is "search is nil"..i am really frustrated why it is nil..Please help me..what was the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SPSearch` doesn't take `ws.spotify.com` links.

Instead, give it the search phrase directly (and not URL encoded), like this:

```
SPSearch *search = [SPSearch searchWithSearchQuery:@"kaisers orchestra"
                                         inSession:[SPSession sharedSession]];
```

Comment: Hi dude..its working for me..i want to know one more things..i am having SPAlbums or SPArtists objects..how can i fetch all SPTracks from these Albums and tracks ? please help me